# React - How to pass props on click text to image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple app, where I'm looking for a solution to connect the click from the text to the image. Here, the click is not toggeable, **just click once and the image is supposed to appear.** First, I thought that would make sense to define a state for the image, but honestly I don't think is the best practice.

Which is the best solution for this kind of situation? I aprecciate any provided tips and solutions.

Thank you.

```js
// IMAGE COMPONENT
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          alt=""
          src="https://media.makeameme.org/created/what-if-I-y0ivox.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// TEXT COMPONENT
class Text extends React.Component {
  imageClick() {
    console.log('click');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={this.imageClick}>If you click me, Morpheus will appear!</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// PARENT COMPONENT
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Text onClick={this.imageClick} />
        <Image src={this.props.src} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
 <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parent component to set the visibility of the image.

```
// IMAGE COMPONENT
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          alt=""
          src="https://media.makeameme.org/created/what-if-I-y0ivox.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// TEXT COMPONENT
class Text extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>If you click me, Morpheus will appear!</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// PARENT COMPONENT
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible : false,
   }
   toggleVisible = () => this.setState({ visible : !this.state.visible });

  render () {
  const { visible } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Text onClick={this.toggleVisible} />
        {
          visible 
          && <Image src={this.props.src} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("#app"));
```

Comment: I get this error: `this.SetState is not a function` @Joseba

Comment: Write setState instead of SetState.

Comment: Thank you! @EhssanMajdabadi